# the number of the longest paths of a complete undirected graph $K_n$

Tags: combinatorics, graph-theory

I am trying to find the number of the longest paths of a complete undirected graph $K_n$.  My guess is $\frac{n!}{2}$. Any longest path in $K_n$ should have $n$ vertices. And given one longest path $v_1 - v_2 - \dots - v_n$ by ordering $n$ vertices, the only path which is same with the given one is $v_n - v_{n-1} - \dots - v_1$. Thus, we have $\frac{n!}{2}$.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: As you have interpreted the problem, that is the correct count.  In many contexts a path may be distinguished from its reversal, i.e. a *directed* path.  But I'm willing to assume you know the context sufficiently to make the identification of the two.

Comment: @hardmath I should have said that I assume that a graph here is undirected. Thank you!